# Как подключаться по API

Tags: php, laravel, api

У меня есть сайт, с которого нужно передавать значения полей на другой сайт.
Прогер другого сайта сказал, что нужно использовать такой метод передачи: "Формируете строку json, потом добавляете к ней секрет, потом от этого md5-хеш и отправляете строку json и хеш"
Я совсем не знаю, как это делать. Можете прислать названия книг/ссылки на видеоуроки, где можно этому научиться?

Comment: Открой гугол и вводи запросы.

Answer (score 2):

Функция [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) конвертирует данные в строку JSON. JSON - это обычная текствоая строка, которая содержит ваши данные, например из ассоциативного массива. По предоставленной ссылке, чуть ниже, есть примеры использования.

Функция [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.md5) возвращает MD5 хеш любой текстовой строки. Скорее всего имелось в виду что вам нужно взять строку что у вас получилась после json_encode, добавить к ней некую секретную строку (которую знаете только вы и получатель), а затем получить из итогового варианта MD5 при помощи соответствующей функции

Затем, для проверки подлинности, вы высылаете саму строку (без секретной строки естественно) и хеш (который получился из строки с секретным ключом). Высылать можно, например при помощи curl (там вы сможете выбрать тип запроса, POST или GET), либо, если достаточно GET запроса, при помощи банального `file_get_contents("http://адрес-апи-получателя")`.

P.S. Скорее всего подразумевалось что секрет вам должны сообщить, либо вы должны его придумать и сообщить принимающей стороне. Также вам должны были сказать куда конкретно слать (адрес API)

Answer (score 0):

Отправлять json строку на другой сервер используя API можно написав 10 строчек кода в Laravel.

```
    <?

    public function sendRequest() {
            $data = [
                    'parameter1' => 'value1',
                    'parameter2' => 'value2',
            ];

            $jsonData = json_decode($data);
            $jsonUrl = "http://api.example.com";

            $ch = curl_init($jsonUrl);
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonData
            );
            curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
            $result =  curl_exec($ch);
            Log::info($result);
            curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Из вашего сообщения не до конца понятно как именно формировать и в каком виде отправлять хеш. Хеш формирует следующая функция php

```
    $hash = hash_hmac('md5', $content, $secret);
```